# Base table not found for civicrm_contribution_page #201

Tags: drupal-views, civicrm-entity, drupal-8

On latest version of 8.x-3.x branch i get following error when try to add a view for contribution page

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'civicrmdb.civicrm_contribution_page' doesn't exist: SELECT civicrm_contribution_page.id AS id FROM {civicrm_contribution_page} civicrm_contribution_page LIMIT 11 OFFSET 0; Array ( )

views for Contact, Contribution, Event works fine but not incase of Contribution page, Payment processor, campaign etc.

Can we create list of contribution pages/campaigns/payment processors using  civicrm_entity + civicrm views d8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when you have separate database for civicrm tables. Below patch in civicrm_entity module fixes problem for `'Base table or view not found:'`

```
diff --git a/src/CivicrmEntityViewsData.php b/src/CivicrmEntityViewsData.php
index 51db201..ffbb31d 100644
--- a/src/CivicrmEntityViewsData.php
+++ b/src/CivicrmEntityViewsData.php
@@ -17,6 +17,8 @@ class CivicrmEntityViewsData extends EntityViewsData {
     $base_table = $this->entityType->getBaseTable() ?: $this->entityType->id();
     $base_field = $this->entityType->getKey('id');

+    $database = _civicrm_get_db_config()['key'];
+
     // Setup base information of the views data.
     $data[$base_table]['table']['group'] = sprintf('%s (CiviCRM Entity)', $this->entityType->getLabel());
     $data[$base_table]['table']['provider'] = $this->entityType->getProvider();
@@ -27,6 +29,7 @@ class CivicrmEntityViewsData extends EntityViewsData {
       'field' => $base_field,
       'title' => $this->entityType->getLabel(),
       'cache_contexts' => $this->entityType->getListCacheContexts(),
+      'database' => $database,
     ];
     $data[$base_table]['table']['entity revision'] = FALSE;
     if ($label_key = $this->entityType->getKey('label')) {
```

Comment: We've been using the same "CMS Database Integration" code that would go into the Drupal settings.php as was in D7 but perhaps this is better. Will check it out.